# Reading Unstructured Text from the entire file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, etl, azure-synapse

I have a file which is present as a unstructured txt in ADLS. I want to read the entire file content as text and pass it to a Stored Procedure in Azure data factory. Can this be done through Azure data factory? Below is an example of the file:

```
Number: 101095
This is a sample 1

ABC

XYZ

END
Number: 101096
This is a sample 2

ABC2

XYZ2

hhhh2

END
Number: 101096
This is a sample 3

ABC3

XYZ3

MMMM3

END
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for the above input? and also provide source and targets for the above pipeline run.

Comment: The source is already provided. Its a text file in ADLS. The target is Stored Procedure.  The expected output is- " I want to pass this text to a stored proc in Data factory".

Comment: from this file what you want to pass to stored procedure?

Comment: The complete content of the file

Answer (score 0):

> I want to read the entire file content as text and pass it to a Stored Procedure in Azure data factory.

To read entire content from .txt file you need to use lookup activity.

[image]

Add the ADLS dataset with .txt file and column and row delimiter character which is not present in your data example " **`** ".

[image]

data preview of file:

[image]

Then you can access it using `@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].Prop_0`

Comment: Thanks, the sample data was just an example. The solution assumes that the delimiter '`' is not present in the file, but that is not the case. The file contents are dynamic and currently I cannot confirm which character will not be present in the incoming file. Is there still a way to achieve this through ADF?